# Install Sonata Ecommerce

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am install Sonata Ecommerce bundle in my project for using Ecommerce functionality.
I follow this doc : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/ecommerce/master/doc/reference/installation.html

As per manual part when I Run the easy-extends:generate commands
then show me error :

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: seo in /var/www/xyz.com/vendor/sonata-project/ecommerce/src/Sonata/ProductBundle/DependencyInjection/SonataProductExtension.php line 317
```

Any one suggest me why ?
This is Sonata Ecommerce bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been reported on github (see https://github.com/sonata-project/ecommerce/issues/7) - maybe by you - and is now fixed. This fix is available on the develop branch however, so you may have to switch to this branch to complete your installation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after fixing this problem again error in new SonataEcommerceBundle file occurred When I was trying to install on my project. I have open new issue on git hub ...

Comment: We are currently looking at it, we'll answer to you shortly on github.